# Probability Distribution of a given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)=10e^{-10x}$.

The cdf for this distribution is $-e^{-10x}+1$

Find $P(X>x_1+x_2\mid X>x_1)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive real numbers.

My method of solving this was to integrate the $-e^{-10x}+1$ bounded to $x_1+x_2$ to $X$ but the end result $e^{-10x}-e^{-10x_1+x_2}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of conditional probability, $$\Pr[X > x_1 + x_2 \mid X > x_1] = \frac{\Pr[(X > x_1 + x_2) \cap (X > x_1)]}{\Pr[X > x_1]} = \frac{\Pr[X > x_1 + x_2]}{\Pr[X > x_1]},$$ since the event that $X > x_1 + x_2$ is a subset of the event $X > x_1$ when $x_2 \ge 0$.  Now note that $$\Pr[X > x] = 1 - \Pr[X \le x] = 1 - (1 - e^{-\lambda x}) = e^{-\lambda x},$$ where $\lambda = 10$ is the rate parameter.  So, what do you conclude?